# Получить размер жесткого диска из /proc или /sys

Tags: linux, lxc

Как Получить размер жесткого диска из /proc или /sys ?
Я в контейнере. /dev пустой.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что в /proc или /sys будет размер диска? Смотрите mount или df, дальше по ситуации

Comment: а у udisk спросить не вариант?

Comment: @andreymail, а почему вы решили, что не будет? Всё же зависит от типа взаимодействия с ядром ОС.

Comment: @andreymal диска, а не раздела

Comment: В `/proc/partitions` не смотря на название файла есть не только разделы, но и размеры физических устройств (даже если на них отсутствуют таблицы разделов)

Answer (score 2):

Например, `/sys/class/block/sd?/size` — размер, судя по всему, в 512-байтовых блоках.

Comment: На счёт того, в каких именно блоках лучше лишний раз проверить, можно, например, на CD, если есть...

Comment: Нет... для CD тоже выдаёт в 512-байтовых блоках....